# About Azure Table Secondary Index

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I know the Secondary Index(s) is not here yet: [It's in wish list and "planed"](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/396314-support-secondary-indexes)

I like to get some ideas (or information from the reliable source) about the incoming secondary index(s)

**1st question**: I noticed MS planed "secondary **indexes**": is that mean we can create as many indexes as we want on one table

**2nd question**: Current index is "`PartitionKey+RowKey`", if above question is not true, will the secondary index be "`RowKey+PartitionKey`" or we have a good chance that we can customize it?

I like to gain some ideas because I am currently design a table, since the data won't much from beginning, so I think I can wait for the secondary index feature without create multiple tables at this moment.

Please share you ideas or any source you have, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, we don't allow questions asking for "opinions" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Windows Azure MVP I don't have any information about the secondary indexes in table service. If we do need more indexes in table service, but don't want use SQL Azure, (Not just because of the pricing...) then I would like to de-normalization my data, which split the same data into more than one table, with different row key as the indexes.

Comment: Thanks. Will the secondary index be (at least) "RowKey+PartitionKey" is a good guess?

Answer (score 4):

There's currently no information on secondary indexes, other than what's written at the site you referenced. So, there's no way to answer either of your two questions.

Several customers I work with, that use Table Storage, have taken the multiple-table approach to provide additional indexing. For those requiring extensive index coverage, that data typically has found its way into SQL Azure (or a combination of SQL Azure + Table Storage).

Comment: Thanks. Will the secondary index be (at least) "RowKey+PartitionKey" is a good guess?

Comment: No way to tell - there's simply no information about secondary indexes. Sorry!

Comment: I've asked about secondary indexes with every MS employee that has anything to do with Azure that I've come across (notably none of them are on the storage team) and none of them had any idea when/if this was coming.

Answer (score 2):

This question is now two years old.  And still no sign of secondary indexes in Azure Table Storage.  My guess is that it is now very unlikely to ever eventuate.

Comment: Yeah, ATS seems to, err, have some very limited use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos DB provides the Table API for applications that are written for Azure Table storage and that need capabilities like:

**Automatic Secondary Indexing**

From: [Introduction to Azure Cosmos DB: Table API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/introduction)

So if you are willing to move your tables over to Cosmos, then you will get all the indexing you could ever want.